# Understanding SQL Server CTE with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thank you to Thom A for providing a solution to this scenario [Columns (where value not null) to Other Ordered Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76885037/columns-where-value-not-null-to-other-ordered-columns/76885138?noredirect=1#comment135565892_76885138).

I thought I post a new question specific to the CTE. When I run the following code, but with only selecting from one row the results are correct expected. However, when I run the code with multiple values, the results are not as expected.

This works:

```
WITH RNs AS
(
    SELECT 
        V.YourIDColumn,
        U.I,
        U.Col,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IIF(U.Col IS NULL, 1, 0), U.I) AS RN
    FROM 
        (VALUES (1, null, 'pink', 'red', null, null, 'orange')) V (YourIDColumn, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF)
    CROSS APPLY 
        (VALUES (1, ColA), (2, ColB), (3, ColC), (4, ColD),
                (5, ColE), (6, ColF)) U (I, Col)
)
SELECT 
    YourIDColumn,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN Col END) AS ColA,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN Col END) AS ColB,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN Col END) AS ColC,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 4 THEN Col END) AS ColD,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 5 THEN Col END) AS ColE,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 6 THEN Col END) AS ColF
FROM
    RNs
GROUP BY 
    YourIDColumn;
```

This (multiple rows) does not:

```
WITH RNs AS
(
    SELECT 
        V.YourIDColumn,
        U.I,
        U.Col,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IIF(U.Col IS NULL, 1, 0), U.I) AS RN
    FROM 
        (VALUES (1, NULL, 'pink', 'red', NULL, NULL, 'orange'), 
                (2, 'yellow', NULL, NULL, 'green', NULL, 'black')) V (YourIDColumn, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF)
    CROSS APPLY 
        (VALUES (1, ColA), (2, ColB), (3, ColC), (4, ColD),
                (5, ColE), (6, ColF)) U (I, Col)
)
SELECT 
    YourIDColumn,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN Col END) AS ColA,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN Col END) AS ColB,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN Col END) AS ColC,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 4 THEN Col END) AS ColD,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 5 THEN Col END) AS ColE,
    MAX(CASE RN WHEN 6 THEN Col END) AS ColF
FROM
    RNs
GROUP BY 
    YourIDColumn;
```

Interested in understanding why this does not run as expected and what I can learn from this. Regards.

Comment: YOu need to add a `PARTITION BY` to the `ROW_NUMBER` on `YourIDColumn`. As the original example only had one row it wasn't needed and so I'd omitted the clause (and, in truth, the `GROUP BY` wasn't needed for one row either)

Comment: I wouldn't expand this out and then `GROUP BY` id - should be quicker to not do that

Comment: I've suggested multiple times to the OP to normalise their data, @MartinSmith . They seem to be against it.

Comment: I meant even with this data structure they don't need to multiply the rows out 6x and then group that. They can just calculate it for each row

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and advice.  When using partition_by with row_number how is the order by clause used?

Comment: e.g., the following doesn't mix up the values from different rows and require re-grouping them https://dbfiddle.uk/Ms3ET-Ed

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By YourIDColumn ORDER BY IIF(U.Col IS NULL, 1,0), U.I) as RN seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

With your "multiple rows" example if you just do

```
SELECT * FROM RNs
```

Then you can see what is going on. The row numbering is being applied to the values from all rows.

```
+--------------+---+--------+----+
| YourIDColumn | I |  Col   | RN |
+--------------+---+--------+----+
|            2 | 1 | yellow |  1 |
|            1 | 2 | pink   |  2 |
|            1 | 3 | red    |  3 |
|            2 | 4 | green  |  4 |
|            2 | 6 | black  |  5 |
|            1 | 6 | orange |  6 |
|            1 | 1 | NULL   |  7 |
|            2 | 2 | NULL   |  8 |
|            2 | 3 | NULL   |  9 |
|            1 | 4 | NULL   | 10 |
|            1 | 5 | NULL   | 11 |
|            2 | 5 | NULL   | 12 |
+--------------+---+--------+----+
```

As discussed in the comments you can add a `PARTITION By YourIDColumn` into that so it does the numbering within each partition

```
+--------------+---+--------+----+
| YourIDColumn | I |  Col   | RN |
+--------------+---+--------+----+
|            1 | 2 | pink   |  1 |
|            1 | 3 | red    |  2 |
|            1 | 6 | orange |  3 |
|            1 | 1 | NULL   |  4 |
|            1 | 4 | NULL   |  5 |
|            1 | 5 | NULL   |  6 |
|            2 | 1 | yellow |  1 |
|            2 | 4 | green  |  2 |
|            2 | 6 | black  |  3 |
|            2 | 2 | NULL   |  4 |
|            2 | 3 | NULL   |  5 |
|            2 | 5 | NULL   |  6 |
+--------------+---+--------+----+
```

But I'd probably just do this calculation for each row individually any way - so `N` sorts of `<=6` rows - rather than a single sort of `6*N` rows plus grouping operation.

As sorting does not have linear complexity this should be preferable and less memory required.

```
WITH DummyData(YourIDColumn, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF)
     AS (SELECT 1,null, 'pink', 'red', null, null, 'orange' UNION ALL
         SELECT 2,'yellow', null, null, 'green', null, 'black'
)
SELECT YourIDColumn,
       CA.[1] AS ColA,
       CA.[2] AS ColB,
       CA.[3] AS ColC,
       CA.[4] AS ColD,
       CA.[5] AS ColE,
       CA.[6] AS ColF
FROM   DummyData
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY U.I) AS RN,
                                   Col
                            FROM   (VALUES(1, ColA),
                                          (2, ColB),
                                          (3, ColC),
                                          (4, ColD),
                                          (5, ColE),
                                          (6, ColF))U(I, Col)
                            WHERE  U.Col IS NOT NULL) D
                           PIVOT (MAX(Col)
                                 FOR RN IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])) P) CA
```