# Reversing hierarchy columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have several hierarchy columns that I've populated in a table. I would like to populate the reverse of those columns, but don't know how to handle an unknown number of null values.

[image: Sample Existing Table]

[image: What I'd like the table to look like]

I could populate these columns with quite a few update statements, but I think there's got to be an easier/cleaner way.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here either. What is the difficulty *you* are having achieving your goal? What about your attempts didn't work? What were those attempts? What about the content you've read to help you solve the problem didn't you understand?

Comment: That database modeling could use some improvement. It's static and difficult to manage. You can use a parent-child linking instead, that could be much more flexible. Also, you are mixing the *rendering* of the hierachy with its *structure*.

Comment: The bigger issue I see here is your table violates 1NF by using repeating groups. What are you going to do when you need L6? Or L204? With your design you have to keep adding columns to your table to handle changes in requirements.

Comment: What inputs are possible and how would you like to compute its reverse?

Comment: You can tweak the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76901165/73226 - though I might use `CHOOSE` instead here and dynamically calculate the correct number to use if it is guaranteed that the original columns only have `NULL` at the end and not in arbitrary positions

Comment: But echoing the above if the data was normalised you wouldn't have to do this sort of thing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source columns are ordered such that they always have 0 or more `NOT NULL` columns followed by the remainder of the columns being `NULL` then you can use ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/svfCvDaV))

```
UPDATE mt
        SET RevL1 = CHOOSE(idx-0, L1, L2, L3, L4, L5), 
            RevL2 = CHOOSE(idx-1, L1, L2, L3, L4, L5), 
            RevL3 = CHOOSE(idx-2, L1, L2, L3, L4, L5), 
            RevL4 = CHOOSE(idx-3, L1, L2, L3, L4, L5), 
            RevL5 = CHOOSE(idx-4, L1, L2, L3, L4, L5)
FROM @MyTable mt
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
        CASE 
            WHEN L5 = L5 THEN 5
            WHEN L4 = L4 THEN 4
            WHEN L3 = L3 THEN 3
            WHEN L2 = L2 THEN 2
            WHEN L1 = L1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END 
))V(idx)
```

`idx` is the index of the last `NOT NULL` column